# Removing listeners from an ace-editor

Tags: ace-editor

With `editor.on('change', ...)` I added a listener, now I need to remove it again. `editor.off(fromEditorOnReturnedFunction)` didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`off` needs event name too

```
editor.on('change', fn)
editor.off('change', fn)
```

also note that on returns function it was passed, so `editor.on('change', fn) == fn`